# Make a chevron tipped block in CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a shape like the one depicted below in pure CSS? How could I go about doing it?

I would like a horizontal solid-filled block on a solid background, with a chevron at one end separated from the main block.

[image: Example of what I would like to achieve]

Comment: Have you tried searching for this, or are you familiar with CSS?

Comment: I'm familiar and I have tried searching

Comment: Is the black part of the pattern, or is the blue? Are either the blue or the black actually transparent, or are they indeed solid colors?

Comment: Really? http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this with just a few background gradients:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient( -45deg, white 25px, transparent 25px),
        linear-gradient(-135deg, white 25px, transparent 25px),
        linear-gradient( -45deg, black 40px, transparent 40px),
        linear-gradient(-135deg, black 40px, transparent 40px),
        linear-gradient( -45deg, white 50px, transparent 50px),
        linear-gradient(-135deg, white 50px, transparent 50px);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/fxj3u/

The code above doesn't have any of the required vendor prefixes for `linear-gradient`. In order to use it in your project you will need to either provide all of the prefixes, or you can simply reference a tool like [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) (which is what I use).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can, you will need to construct it out of several different shapes. You want to make these shapes in this order:

1. Black rectangle
2. Black triangle with purple background
3. Purple triangle with black background
4. Black triangle with purple background

Have a look at http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ for how to create the shapes. Give it a shot and come back with your CSS/Markup if you get stuck.

Something to be weary of: You will probably need to use `float:left;` so the shapes sit next to each other without any gap between them.